# macOS VPS: How do I allow incoming connections if it is an OpenVPN client?

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, mac-osx, vps

When I use OpenVPN as a client on a macOS VPS, it drops the connection with me and I'm no longe able to connect via SSH or VNC. How can I avoid such problem?

Here is my `.ovpn` config file

```
client
float
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify 3
dev tun
remote abc.com 1234
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher none
auth none
verb 3
mssfix 1500
rcvbuf 3932160
sndbuf 3932160
auth-user-pass

<ca>...</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
```

Comment: don't route the network you're coming from into the tunnel...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to configure [Viscosity app](https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/routing-traffic-for-websites-applications/#specifying-traffic-to-go-through-the-normal-network) to solve this problem.